# How to implement a many-to-many relationship with a limited number of relations on one side? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, database-normalization

I'm working on a teambuilding tool for an RPG I play; I'm using MySQL for my database, and InnoDB for the storage engine.

In the game, monsters have 5 slots for skills that you can add via an item, and the order they're kept in is significant (oldest skill gets overwritten if a new skill is added with no free slots) - currently, I have the `monsters` table setup like so:

```
monster_id int not null,
species_id int not null,
user_id int not null,
skill1_id int, # (fkey to skills.skill_id)
skill2_id int, # (fkey to skills.skill_id)
skill3_id int, # (fkey to skills.skill_id)
skill4_id int, # (fkey to skills.skill_id)
skill5_id int, # (fkey to skills.skill_id)
# other irrelevant columns...
```

This keeps the skills in order and prevents a monster from having more skills than the max allowed. However, it doesn't seem like a great solution - this setup doesn't allow me to quickly query "select all monsters who have X skill in any slot." I can query on all 5 slots, but that seems pretty inefficient, since it would rely on a bunch of chained joins (it also wouldn't play nice with the ORM I'm using, though I can drop down to writing my own queries where it's really needed).

If I normalized this relationship using a junction table `monsters_skills` like so:

```
monster_id int not null,
skill_id int not null,
slot_num int not null,
primary key (monster_id, slot_num) # enforce one skill per-slot
```

it would make querying for "all monsters with X skill in any slot" much easier... but the database wouldn't enforce the maximum number of skills-per-monster - as far as I know, MySQL doesn't properly support CHECK constraints, otherwise this would largely solve the issue. I can do the checks in my actual app code, but I vastly prefer the database handling data integrity in all possible cases.

Should I just stick with my current solution (numbered slots in the monsters table), or is there a better way to implement this in MySQL (via table structures, triggers, etc.)?

Comment: The current solution is not great but you can easily query that with `where 1234 in (skill1_id, skill2_id, ..., skill5_id)` using `1234` as an example of a skill_id

Comment: You can use triggers to enforce maximum slot_num.

Answer (score 0):

Learn how to use triggers in SQL. You need to have the DBMS enforce integrity. In general you aren't going to be able to get away with always using a perverse design and MySQL's subset of SQL's pitiful collection of declarative constraints. (Your current design isn't constrained to only valid states anyway, is it?) (You don't actually say how a row maps to an ordered list of skills, for querying, and how an ordered list of skills maps to a row, for updating. But you appear to rely on correct update by users/procedures.)